# How can I hide a folder on my desktop?

Tags: directory, hidden-files

I have tried to use a dot (.) to hide a file/folder and it works fine within the **Home>>Desktop** menu . I tried hiding a folder `Applesauce` by renaming it to `.Applesauce` it was shown as hidden when accessed using the **Home>>Desktop** menu but the folder was still visible on the desktop .

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but if you want to hide the folder, why did you make it a subfolder to Desktop in the first place?

Comment: 16.04, unable to reproduce, it is properly hidden here. Press Ctrl + R to refresh your desktop. Ctrl + H to toggle hidden files visibility on file manager, toggle doesn't work while desktop is selected.

Comment: You probably have enabled showing hidden files. Its possible to disable that in file manager preferences

Comment: Have you tried pressing CTRL + H? It is supposed to hid/unhid dot folders.

Comment: @Serg: qualifies as an answer.  Would you do the honours instead of bad answer below?

Comment: @Fabby answer posted and expanded.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably enabled showing hidden files. It's possible to disable that in 3 ways:

1. **Edit -> Preferences** , and uncheck **Show hidden and backup files**
2. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in file manager
3. Open **View** menu and click **Show hidden files** ( same as #2 )

Answer (score 0):

After naming the folder with a `.` at the start, refresh the desktop by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.